# Unable to understand the difference between different monaco editor packages integration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, monaco-editor, neutrino

I have a react application, and I want to embed Monaco Editor into my application mainly for SQL validation and AutoComplete scenarios. I use `neutrinorc.js` to configure plugins or direct install using `npm install plugin-name` in the application.

My `webpack.config.js` looks like,

```
// Whilst the configuration object can be modified here, the recommended way of making
// changes is via the presets' options or Neutrino's API in `.neutrinorc.js` instead.
// Neutrino's inspect feature can be used to view/export the generated configuration.
const neutrino = require('neutrino');

module.exports = neutrino().webpack();
```

I noticed that there is,
https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor
https://github.com/jaywcjlove/react-monacoeditor

And Microsoft ones,
https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin
https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor

I don't understand that if I want to embed a Monaco Editor into my React application which of the above packages do I need and do I need to configure them in `neutrinorc.js`?

It would be great if someone can explain this in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know neutrinorc.js, but I can explain the other aspects. Integrating Monaco in a React app requires 2 things:

1. A React wrapper for the Monaco editor. You can either write one yourself or use the [react-monaco-editor](https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor) node module.
2. You have to configure webpack to load the required files. This is where [monaco-editor-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin) comes in.

Especially the second point is a bit tricky, depending on your app. If you created that using CRA (create-react-app) you will not have access to the webpack config file, unless you "eject" the app. This is usually not desirable, hence add another node module to the mix, called [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired). This module allows you to add another webpack config file (config-overrides.js) to the root of your project and add configuration data there. Something like:

```js
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    config.plugins.push(new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
        languages: ["typescript", "javascript", "sql", "mysql", "python", "json", "markdown", "ini", "xml"]
    })

    return config;
}
```

With that webpack plugin you can decide which language you want to support in Monaco and distribute only those files required by them (especially TS + JS require quite large files to be there).